# Is ActionFilterAttribute instantiated for each action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, webapi

I want to have a field in ActionFilterAttribute that is only relevant for the action it lives in eg

```
    public class TimedAction : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        long start, end;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            start = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);

            end = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
        }
    }
```

**is it safe to assume that TimedAction will be instantiated for each API call action?**

EDIT: I changed code to this and now it appears requests are shared (what??) and I get exception when I try to add keyvaluepair: `An item with the same key has already been added.`

```
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context)
        {
            var start = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

            context.Request.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Stopwatch", start));

            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(context);

            var end = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

            object o;
            long start = 0;
            if (context.Request.Properties.TryGetValue("Stopwatch", out o))
            {
                start = (long)o;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Give your class a constructor.  Put a breakpoint on it, and figure it out in a debugger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do that, as attributes are statically defined. You need to store that in the request, for example, `HttpContext.Current.Items["SomeKey"]`:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Items["Now"] = DateTime.UtcNow;

    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
}

public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    var beginning = (DateTime) HttpContext.Current.Items["Now"];

    var end = DateTime.UtcNow;

    var interval = end - beginning;

    base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
}
```

Comment: That is in ASP.NET MVC, not ASP.NET Web API, mind you! This code sample is for ASP.NET Web API! See documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh834934(v%3Dvs.108)

Comment: So it is! I missed that in the tags. Ignore me.

Comment: see the edit pls - why request isn't new instance every time I enter action?

Comment: Did you try my approach?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no difference between what I did (see the code in the OP) and @RicardoPeres approach.

The problem was that I accidentally set attribute twice to a method.

Yet I feel Ricardo's version is better than mine so I kept it.